# Is it possible to trigger "Email Quote" QuickAction from Aura Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email, attachment, quickaction, quote

I've got an Aura Component modal launched from Opportunity which reviews and creates a Quote, redirects the user on the new quote page, and create a PDF (apex call).

What I want to do is to open an email composer with the quote PDF attached and a template body loaded, automatically when the PDF is generated. I can catch when the PDF is generated in the callback function. Do I have to create a custom email composer or can I use a SendEmail QuickAction directly in Aura / LWC and attach the QuoteDocument ? I tried something like this that doesnt seem to work:

```
                    var navService = component.find("navService");
                    var pageReference = {
                        type: 'standard__quickAction',
                        attributes: {
                            apiName: 'Global.SendEmail'
                        },
                        state: {
                            "recordId": response.getReturnValue() 
                        }
                    };
                    var defaultFieldValues = {
                        HtmlBody: "Test",
                        Subject: "Test subject",
                    }

                    pageReference.state.defaultFieldValues = component.find("pageRefUtil").encodeDefaultFieldValues(defaultFieldValues);
                    navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

Thanks in advance for the advices :)

Comment: I ended up creating a custom email composer with LWC, i was unable to find a way to attach a file with standard quickactions